# Saving data to multiple tables with dependency injection and maintaining transection in asp.net core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, repository, unit-of-work

I have simple classes to saves and get data (not like repository pattern). But while saving data to multiple tables I want to maintain a transaction. So I just went through Unit of work pattern, but that will require me to do a lot of changes. So I'm thinking if my approach will do the same as UOF.

Here's my code:

`CalalogueRepository:`

```
 public interface ICalalogueRepository
{
    void Create(string guid, string fileName);
}

public class CalalogueRepository : ICalalogueRepository
{
    private CatalogueContext _catalogueContext;
    public CalalogueRepository(CatalogueContext catalogueContext)
    {
        _catalogueContext = catalogueContext;
    }
    public void Create(string guid, string fileName)
    {
         _catalogueContext.Catalogues.Add(new Catalogue
            {
                CatalogueId = guid,
                FileName = fileName
            });
    }
}
```

`StuffRepo:`

```
public interface IStuffRepo
{
    void Create(string guid, List<StuffModel> myStuff);
}

public class StuffRepo : IStuffRepo 
{
    private CatalogueContext _catalogueContext;
    public StuffRepo(CatalogueContext catalogueContext)
    {
        _catalogueContext = catalogueContext;
    }
    public void Create(string guid, List<StuffModel> myStuff)
    {
        //add stuff to _catalogueContext.StuffTable.Add
    }
}
```

Finally a class that does the `SaveChanges` and `Commit`:

```
public class UOW : IUOW
{
    private CatalogueContext _catalogueContext;
    private ICalalogueRepository _calalogueRepo;
    private IStuffRepo _stuffRepo;
    public UOW(CatalogueContext catalogueContext,
                ICalalogueRepository calalogueRepo,
                IStuffRepo stuffRepo)
    {
        _catalogueContext = catalogueContext;
        _calalogueRepo = calalogueRepo;
        _stuffRepo = stuffRepo;
    }

    public void Save (string guid, string fileName, List<StuffModel> myStuff)
    {
        using (IDbContextTransaction transection = _catalogueContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _calalogueRepo.Create(guid, fileName);
            _stuffRepo.Create (guid, myStuff);
            _catalogueContext.SaveChanges();
            transection.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I think there is only 1 `CatalogueContext` throughout the call.

Comment: How did you register your CatalogueContext in the services container in Startup.cs?

Comment: @Akos  `services.AddDbContext<CatalogueContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CatalogueDbContext")));`

Answer (score 0):

- Ok, so as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection), AddDbContext is the right way to register it as you wrote in the comment on the question.
- [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#implicitly-sharing-dbcontext-instances-across-multiple-threads-via-dependency-injection) it says that AddDbContext will register the context as scoped.
- [And here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes) you can find what scoped means.

Overall I think you are right that your code will use the same context throughout the Save method.

Couple thoughts:

- Probably you want to have a try-catch in case an exception is thrown and you want to rollback
- If you are not sure if it's working why not try it? You should test your code/application anyways.
- Probably this could be done in a better way, but I don't have the context about the rest of your code/application, so I cannot tell. (Not sure what you mean by "...Unit of work pattern, but that will require me to do a lot of changes." for example.)
- Now the Create methods not self-contained, meaning if you just want to add a new item to the table it is not enough to call Create, but separately call SaveChanges(). This is not an explicit problem, but has to be kept in mind and might be a little bit confusing for new developers on the project.